# MySQL (Stored) Procedure - parameters and query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a simple procedure with parameters.

```
CALL new_procedure('mode', 'ASC');
```

The first input is the column the second is the sort direction

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(IN in_order_by_column varchar(20), in_order_by_direction char(4))
BEGIN

    DECLARE order_by varchar(30);
    SET @order_by = CONCAT('`', in_order_by_column, '` ', in_order_by_direction);
/*
    SELECT * FROM `common_tags` ORDER BY @order_by  LIMIT 5;
*/
    SELECT @order_by as 'c';

END
```

In the above example I have it only outputting the 2 parameters so I can see what's happening.

Result:

```
"c"
`mode` ASC
```

.

When I run the procedure with it's intended code, below.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(IN in_order_by_column varchar(20), in_order_by_direction char(4))
BEGIN

    DECLARE order_by varchar(30);
    SET @order_by = CONCAT('`', in_order_by_column, '` ', in_order_by_direction);
    SELECT * FROM `common_tags` ORDER BY @order_by  LIMIT 5;

END
```

Results

```
tags_id     data                mode        parent_id       position
1           Wood                2           13              6
2           Trippy              0           0               0
4           Artists             1           0               1
6           "Newest Additions"  1           0               11
12          "Natural Elements"  2           5               8
```

As you can see the results are not sorted by `mode`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to [`PREPARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) entire query in this case:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `new_procedure`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(IN in_order_by_column varchar(20), in_order_by_direction char(4))
BEGIN
    SET @buffer = CONCAT_WS('',
        'SELECT * FROM `common_tags` ORDER BY `', in_order_by_column, '` ', in_order_by_direction, ' LIMIT 5'
    );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @buffer;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**NOTE:** Described approach should be used **very careful**, because it is vulnurable to SQL Injection attacks, if used incorrectly.

Comment: You might want to quote the input values using `quote()`, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote

Comment: @Leukipp OP is trying to costruct query with varying column and direction. Function you're suggesting is designed to escape values, not for column, direction or any query description parts.

Comment: My comment referred to your note on the constructed query being vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: To clarify @Leukipp's suggestion: This specific constructed query only uses parameters as a **column name** and as an **SQL keyword** - using `quote()` would cause an error. The column name is protected from injection by surrounding the column names with back-ticks, as BlitZ does. Leukipp's comment is indeed useful to anyone who uses this technique for parameters that are used in query as **values** (so was useful to me in a different concat'd query, to avoid SQL injection).

Comment: More about SQL injection: `in_order_by_direction` isn't protected; better would be to pass in a bool that is tested, replaced by `ASC` or `DESC` when CONCAT the query. To be safe, every part of the query must be protected by some means.